# Sort 2-dimensional array by elements of inner arrays

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an Array with 8 arrays inside.

It looks like this:

```
[[num,...],[num,...],[num,...],[num,...],[num,...],[num,...],[num,...],[num,...]]
```

Each of this inner arrays has as its first element a number. Now I want to receive the element of the outer array with the biggest number as first element.

How do I do that?

Thank you very much.

Comment: What have you tried? hint: [`foreach()`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: Look into [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define any sorting algorithm by using PHP's [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

```
usort($array, function($a, $b) {
  return $a[0] > $b[0];
});
```

This will sort your array, in place, such that the first element will have the largest number as it's first element.

Comment: Does anybody know, why i get this error: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION" by using this?

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? Run `php -v`

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessary (and is much more expensive) to sort the entire array. Something like this would work:

```
// initially, regard the first element as the largest
$element = $array[0];
$greatest = $array[0][0];

$length = count($array);

// compare the first value of each array against $greatest, swapping $element if it's larger
for($i = 1; $i < $length; $i++) { // N.B. start with second element
    if($array[$i][0] > $greatest) {
        $element = $array[$i];
    }
}

// $element is now the element with the biggest first value
```

Comment: I would agree that this approach is best if you just need the element with highest value. Though OP should check out usort just for future reference, or if they end up needing the entire array sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Check out `usort` : http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

You'll have to write your own comparison function.